# CSS/JavaScript to crop image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How to target a specific location on the image to be cropped using css or javascript, simple way without big scripts,

Picture before :
 [image]

I want the highlighted location on the following image to be viewed :

[image]

Not the exact highlighted though, just trying to explain it doesnt has to be from the very top, i want to select specific image scales, 
**AND how to resize is after cropping ?**

Comment: You can resize it by changing width and height of the container

Comment: @adzaz that actually ruins the position

Comment: Unfortunately that's how it works, every time you change the width and height, you'll have to adjust the position.

Comment: You can crop images in the brwoser side with javascript, now. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update 2022-05-27:** A new property `object-view-box` will soon make this a lot simpler: https://ishadeed.com/article/css-object-view-box/

---

One approach is to use an element with `overflow: hidden` that has the image as a child, which itself is absolutely positioned within the context of the original element. The result being, the size of the `overflow: hidden` element masks the image.

Here's an example of the approach:

HTML

```
<div id='crop-the-cats'>
    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArS4Q.jpg'>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#crop-the-cats {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow:hidden;   
    position:relative;
}

#crop-the-cats img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: -70px;
}
```

*​See http://jsfiddle.net/Da9CT/*

Another approach is to use the image as the background of the image and reposition it using `background-position`:

HTML

```
<div id='crop-the-cats'></div>​
```

CSS

```
#crop-the-cats {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArS4Q.jpg);
    background-position: -50px -60px;
}
```

*​See http://jsfiddle.net/Da9CT/2/*

Comment: well thats a great answer 1++, How can i resize the image size after doing this ?

Comment: @Osa If you mean the container, just change the size of `#crop-the-cats`: http://jsfiddle.net/Da9CT/4/. If you mean the cropped image itself, simply apply `width` and/or `height` rules to `#crop-the-cats img`: http://jsfiddle.net/Da9CT/3/

Comment: You can also position the image without using `position: absolute` by using `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead of `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't crop image using javascript / css but you can position it inside an element with overflow hidden: http://jsbin.com/ebenem/1/edit

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yes you can crop image using javascript, now. Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload