# How to use Image Crop option with Asp: FileUpload control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008, file-upload

I am trying to insert an Image into SQL Server Database in Asp.net by using Asp:FileUpload Control but I want it to be like that:
When user select a image through control It will display in to a image cropping box and after cropping, on Insert button click image will insert into Database.

I've done the whole insert image procedure but I just need help on this crop thing.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following links:

1) http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-crop-image-and-upload-using-jcrop-plugin.html

2)http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET

Comment: These links really helped me, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look to JavaScript and/or jQuery to do this. You can read here for the same question but answered: [Cropping images in the browser BEFORE the upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload)