# html store image for upload on page as data string

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

I have a form that should upload image and then show jquery cropper to let user crop image. I don't want to make a form submit. Is there a way to store selected in

```
 <input file...
```

image content? To prevent uploading. So I select image, then crop it and only after then I save cropped image. Is it possible?

Comment: You're in luck, it's been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping images in the browser BEFORE the upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload)