# Upload and crop image via external image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jcrop

I have fetched the external image via a link (say, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) and have got its dataURL and have converted that dataURL to an image file. How can I crop it on client-side?

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pixastic](https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic) javascript library to crop an image. It also has a lot of other image processing methods that can be used.

[Image cropping example using pixastic](http://dph.am/pixastic-docs/docs/actions/crop/)