# Crop image from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cropper

Is there any chance I can allow user **who is adding image** to the input to actually make crop **before** send it to the server via ajax? I can easy display it via converting to base64 format but then there is no kind of documentation in any of jquery plugin how to generate crop after changed on input detected. I tried cropper.js and Jcrop.js but I can't find such a methods in option - there is only reading from static source cant read via blob type which is add by user to the input. Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload

Comment: check that question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping images in the browser BEFORE the upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload)